# How do I prevent the "Updating Steam" dialog from showing up

Tags: steam

Every time I start Steam, it takes a dozen seconds checking for updates.

[image]

Is there a way to force it to only check for updates on a weekly basis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, there is a way!

In order to hide the update dialog, simply run Steam with the `-silent` command line option.
As usual, any other dialogs (such as going into offline mode due to a lack of internet connection or a missing Steam Service warning) will appear. Those cannot be suppressed.

If you do not want Steam to verify its files (check integrety), run steam with the `-noverifyfiles` command line option.

[You can read the list of command-line options here.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options)

Comment: Hm... Interesting. That's *nearly* what I want. However, the explanation of the `-silent` option in the linked page states: "*suppresses the dialog box that opens when you start steam*. ***It is used when you have Steam set to auto-start when your computer turns on.***" I *do* have Steam set to auto-start when my computer turns on. So, I guess the question is, is it possible to prevent this check from taking place?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy You're essentially asking "How do I stop steam from updating?" | Also, when Steam auto-starts, it doesn't suppress the update dialog.

Comment: I don't want to stop Steam from updating, but I'd really love to *decrease the frequency* of the check. Is that posible?

Comment: That's what my edit addresses — Use the `-noverifyfiles` command line option.